# Can i make this more efficient when scaling the project up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, interactive

Okay, so i am building a website for an industrial company that have created some new technology. Now on the how it works page, they want an interactive way for the user to dig deep into how the machine works.

This company have CAD software which created 3d images that can be rotated etc.. So my idea is to basically have them screen shot every signle step they need. For example

It starts with the main product. If you hover over certain parts of this image it will change colour to show that you can click it. When you click the link(hotspot) it will take you to that part(which may or may not have another parts they can did into even further).

They really like this idea and concept , i have created a very small prototype of this that i have shown the client and they love the idea. Now this is the part where im a little worried. I know that i can acheive this the way i have built my prototype, however it will very quickly become a huge mess of javascript. There will be around 200 images from them, and im only using like 5 for my prototype.

jsfiddle here = https://jsfiddle.net/erxrp4vr/

This is my code:

```
       //First tier hot spots
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var mainHotspot = '<img id="mainImage" src="img/car.png" border="0" width="475" height="311" orgWidth="475" orgHeight="311" usemap="#image-maps-2015-11-26-071629" alt="" /><map name="image-maps-2015-11-26-071629" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2015-11-26-071629"><area shape="rect" coords="473,309,475,311" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" /><area id="engine" alt="" title="" shape="poly" coords="155,128,141,131,125,134,121,134,110,132,102,132,106,141,104,153,103,162,100,169,97,171,89,173,99,181,104,191,106,198,125,199,142,201,150,198,156,193,165,187,168,181,177,191,184,187,178,172,180,165,181,159,175,152,173,145,168,138,168,132,164,128" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     /><area id="wheel" shape="poly" coords="437,143,423,141,413,147,405,158,402,174,402,188,402,201,410,210,421,212,433,212,446,204,452,189,454,171,453,157,447,149,447,146" style="outline:none;"/></map>'
            var engineImage = '<img id="mainImage" src="img/1.jpg" border="0" width="500" height="375" orgWidth="500" orgHeight="375" usemap="#image-maps-2015-11-26-092546" alt="" /><map name="image-maps-2015-11-26-092546" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2015-11-26-092546"> <area id="enginepart" shape="poly" coords="239,136,240,167,243,190,243,210,266,217,280,207,277,183,273,151,272,143,271,117,262,63,245,107" style="outline:none;"   /> </map>';
            var enginePart  = '<img src="img/1.1.png">'


            var home = '<div class="mainLevel">Car</div>';
            var last = '<div class="secondLevel">Engine</div>';
            $('body').append(mainHotspot);






            //Engine
            $(document).on('mouseover', '#engine', function(){
                $('#mainImage').attr('src','img/carHover.png');
            });
            $(document).on('mouseout', '#engine', function(){
                $('#mainImage').attr('src','img/car.png');
            });
            $(document).on('click', '#engine', function(){
                $('body').empty();
                $('body').append(home + '<br/>');
                $('body').append(engineImage);
            });
                $(document).on('mouseover', '#enginepart', function(){
                    $('#mainImage').attr('src','img/1Hover.png');
                });
                $(document).on('mouseout', '#enginepart', function(){
                    $('#mainImage').attr('src','img/1.jpg');
                });
                $(document).on('click', '#enginepart', function(){
                    $('body').empty();
                    $('body').append(home + ' / ' + last + '<br/>');
                    $('body').append(enginePart);
                });


            //Wheel
            $(document).on('mouseover', '#wheel', function(){
                $('#mainImage').attr('src','img/wheelHover.png');
            } );
            $(document).on('mouseout', '#wheel', function(){
                $('#mainImage').attr('src','img/car.png');
            } );


            //BreadCrumbs
            $(document).on('click', '.mainLevel', function(){
                $('body').empty();
                $('body').append(mainHotspot);
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.secondLevel', function(){
                $('body').empty();
                $('body').append(home + ' <br/> ' );
                $('body').append(engineImage);
            });
```

So as you can see this is a really bad way of doing it, it will work but i want to find a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Have you looked into `canvas` and `svg` ?

Comment: I know of them, but always have had trouble when trying to use them

Comment: @MatthewSmart you should look into something like this: http://dev.filkor.org/2013/04/14/create-an-interactive-map-using-javascript-and-html-5-canvas/

Comment: @Joseph would this allow for multiple click throughs?

Comment: @MatthewSmart that should be possible, although I haven't gone through this specific tutorial myself. Here's another one: https://parall.ax/blog/view/2985/tutorial-creating-an-interactive-svg-map which even has a demo that shows how to bind event listeners.